# Do I have to close FileInputStream?

Tags: java, file-io, inputstream

I am working as a trainee in Test Automation.
I am working with creating Junit code with Eclipse and run using Eclipse.
In that I am retriving the datas from excel sheet using FileInputStream function.

```
FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("c:\\search.xls");
Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
```

Is it necessary to close the Inputstream function? If it so please guide me with some codings.

Answer (score 36):

Yes, you need to `close` the inputstream if you want your system resources released back.

[`FileInputStream.close()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#close()) is what you need.

Comment: Is it needed in case of junit tests? Won't be resources released after process exists?

Comment: yeah, after the process exits, there's nothing to utilize. So, OS will reclaim the resource. But the idea is to keep the tests running in a stable manner instead of waiting for the exit to do the job. it's like asking "what if I switch off my device?" :-) Also, it depends on the OS. Check this question on [doesnt-the-jvm-release-all-the-resources-that-are-not-explicitly-closed-by-the-programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654570/doesnt-the-jvm-release-all-the-resources-that-are-not-explicitly-closed-by-the) for more details

Answer (score 10):

You either need to close(), or end your program.

However you can run into confusing issues if you don't close the file as

- sometimes test are run individually or a group of test are run in the same process. (So you could have a test which works one way but not the other)
- you cannot rename or delete an open file.

It is best practice to always close your resources which you are finished with them, however I see unit tests as scripts which don't always have to follow best practice.

Comment: Good reasons for closing resources. I would add `too many open files` and memory leaks to that list, especially for long living processes.

Comment: @Elist it needs to be a long time between GCs as they get closed on clean up.

Comment: True, long life of a process probably isn't usually the cause. More commonly - recursively reading files / directories can cause `too many open files`. Anyway, I have seen both cases myself, so whatever the trigger is, it is a real life scenario.

Answer (score 9):

```
FileInputStream fi=null;
try {
    fi=new FileInputStream("c:\\search.xls");
    Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
    Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
} finally {
    if (fi!=null) {
        fi.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a small comment - you also need to wrap the `close()` statement with a try/catch as `close()` declares to throw a checked IOException. In fact, you can't use finally like that. You can only have a try/finally with runtime exceptions. But with checked exceptions like IOException and subclasses of it, you have to have a try/catch or a try/catch/finally... it won't compile with just try/finally.

Comment: Depends whether IOException is declared for the method. If you catch it, you should know what to do with it. The important part is putting the close() in a finally block. In fact the automatic handling of this is one of the features I'm really looking forward to seeing in Java 7.

Answer (score 6):

It's always a good idea to close resources you use, **BUT**:

If you use resource **A** in resource **B**, it's sensible to close **B** instead of **A** if it has a method for it.

In your case, you use `FileInputStream` in `Workbook`, so you'd better to close `Workbook` and rely on `Workbook` that it will close `FileInputStream`.

In this particular case, actually, `Workbook` [will close](http://www.javadocexamples.com/jxl/jxl.Workbook-source.html) `FileInputStream` at the end of the `getWorkbook()` method but it's still a good idea to [close](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#close%28%29) `Workbook` to be able to be garbage collected.

Comment: This actually is a better answer. I was calling close/release on both the objects.

Comment: @HiteshKumarSaini The fact that a Closeable A class's constructor takes in a Closeable B class type constrctor parameter says nothing about how A will deal with B's close() method. The Workbook class does not close the InputStream. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Yes! you should always release the resources once after you are done with them. Java has a powerful mechanism for Garbage Collection(note that it is different thing compare to resource management/leaks.) 
So a Garbage collector can not determine that if you need the resource in future or not? Failing to release resources may cause issues like- Denial of services, poor performance .

As already answered but another effort less way is [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
    try (FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("c:\\search.xls")) {

         //do something with fi.
         //fi.getChannel() ;

    } catch(IOException e) {
        // exception handling.
    } finally {
    // some statements for finally.
   }
```

Now you don't need to explicitly call fi.close() method.

Answer (score 1):

The Workbook implements the Closeable interface which indicates that you should call the close() method or use a try with resources to free resources acquired by a Workbook object.

You can’t conclude anything on how the InputStream resource is used by the Workbook by simply observing that the Workbook has a close() method.

What really goes on is that the Workbook constructor uses the stream to initialize itself. The constructor does not keep a reference to the stream. The Workbook constructor does not close the InputStream. It is your responsibility to close the InputStream and you can do this immediately after the Workbook object is constructed. The following code is therefore OK:

```
private static Workbook getWorkbook() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream is = ...) {
        return WorkbookFactory.create(is); // newer API
    }
}

    try (Workbook workbook = getWorkbook()) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("SheetName");
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, when I tried to refactor my code, I had to move the workbook creation to another method, and the FileInputStream is created in that method. That method creates a FileInputStream and returns a Workbook. But FileInputStream is not visible from the main method; so how will I close my FileInputStream at the end of main method? The answer is, you don't have to close FileInputStream, instead you just close the workbook, which internally closes FileInputStream. In short, it is  incorrect to say that you must close FileInputStream no matter what.

Comment: But the `Workbook` interface does not have a method called `close`, how do I can close the `Workbook` ?

Comment: Are you sure the Workbook's close() method closes the InputStream? See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I do such a way to ensure to close the excel file input stream, this maybe helps

```
abstract int workWithWorkBook(Workbook workBook);

protected int doWorkBook(Path excelFile) throws IOException {
    File f = excelFile.toFile();

    try (FileInputStream excelContent = new FileInputStream(excelFile.toFile())){
        POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(excelContent);
        Workbook workBook = null;
        if (f.getName().endsWith("xls")) {
            workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);
        } else if (f.getName().endsWith("xlsx")) {
            workBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelContent);
        }
        return workWithWorkBook(workBook);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

9b9ea92b-5b63-47f9-a865-fd40dd602cd5

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
FileInputStream fi=null;
try{
fi = new FileInputStream("c:\\search.xls");
Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
}catch(IOException ioe){
}finally{
if(fi != null){
fi.close();
}
fi = null;//This will be hint to get finalize() called on fi so that underlying resources used will released like files opened.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basic CompSci 101 tell us to make sure to close resources that we open, in Java or any language. So yes, you need to close them. Bad juju is bound to happen when you do not do so.

Also, you should learn (and have the inclination) to use the Javadocs. Look up at the Javadoc for FileInputStream and Closeable. The answers are there.

Comment: It is really awful approach to blindly follow established rules without criticism and understanding the *why?* part. *Bad things will happen* -- oh common?! Programming is not a voodoo magic, without mentioning consequences (**file can't be moved, in general, memory leaks might be introduced, [os pool of file handles might be exausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661322/too-many-open-file-handles)**) of not properly freed resources your answer is useless and moreover harmful. **Downvoted.**

Comment: Oooo, I use a form of speech and you go "ZOMG he believes in voodoo"  (as opposed to "hhhh, he didn't spell it out and opted for some vernacular." There are a quite a few other responses that do not spell out the consequences, and unless you went out to neg-rep them, you are simply climbing a bunch of soap boxes on a biased high horse. Why I don't spell the issues (and why most people in this thread did not)? Because they are easy to find the appropriate literature, available to anyone doing a modicum of research. Your choice if you find that inappropriate.