# SonarQube not capturing FileInputStream which is not closed

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

```
public static String getMD5Checksum(String filePath) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    return DigestUtils.md5Hex(fis);
}
```

In the above code fis is not closed but it is not thrown as error in SonarQube. The DigestUtils.md5Hex method does not close the stream too.
Both SonarQube and Sonar Java plugins are in latest versions.

Answer (score 2):

You don't **use** the `FileInputStream`, but if you add the following line (or similar):

```
fis.read();
```

It will add the valid rule: `Resources should be closed (squid:S2095)`

> Connections, streams, files, and other classes that implement the Closeable interface or its super-interface, AutoCloseable, needs to be closed **after use**.

But you have a point that we need to release resource as [FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090937/do-i-have-to-close-fileinputstream)

> Yes, you need to close the inputstream if you want your system resources released back.

You can raise this question in [SonarSource community](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/bug/fault)

**EDIT**

[Resources should be closed not warns on new FileInputStream](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/resources-should-be-closed-not-warns-on-new-fileinputstream/2882) added as a possible sonarqube bug