# Do I have to close FileInputStream if I close Scanner

Tags: java, java-stream

I have read this question: [Do I have to close FileInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090937)

What if I use a Scanner like this https://www.baeldung.com/java-scanner and close the Scanner? Does the `scanner.close()` close the FileInputStream as well?

Comment: Just look at the source code for class `java.util.Scanner`.

Comment: Or the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#close()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will. Consider the following code:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
scanner.close();
System.out.println(inputStream.read());
```

This throws a `java.io.IOException` because the stream is closed.

Edit: Or, as said by [Slaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6395627/slaw), check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Your answer is mostly correct. It shows the `FileInputStream` will be closed but only by example. There's a much more reliable source of truth—the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html): "_When a `Scanner` is closed, it will close its input source if the source implements the `Closeable` interface_".