# Is there a portable way to find out how many files a JVM has open from inside the VM?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jvm

I am writing tests for some Java file handling code and want to make sure all files are closed properly. I don't want to run 'lsof' as that will open more files and make the test suite non-portable. Anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661322/too-many-open-file-handles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something that's part of the JDK, the answer is no.

You might find something that uses [JVMTI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html), but that wouldn't be portable (it's a native interface). Or something that uses [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/index.html), but that would require a second JVM. I give you those two acronyms as a start for Googling.

If you want to run in-JVM and be portable, you'll have to introduce a factory for your file references: replace all `new FileInputStream()`, `new FileOutputStream()`, `new RandomAccessFile()`, `new FileReader`, and `new FileWriter` calls with methods on that factory object. This factory will return subclasses of these objects, that have the `close()` method overridden. It will also increment an "open files" counter, that is then decremented by the overridden `close()`.

The factory methods and counter will need to be static and synchronized (unless you want to inject the factory), and should use a system property to decide whether to return a subclassed stream or the JDK version.

Personally, I'd take the advice in the comment, and use FindBugs first.